# Is there a way to update a field in rails if same value exists for a different field maintaining its uniqueness?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on user's model in which users will be sorted on the basis of sort_order for them.
What I am trying to achieve is that 
if we set same sort_order for a new user or update existing user, all users with same sort_order are incremented.
For example 
we have 3 user types with their sort_order as follows

---

Gold with sort_order as 1

Diamond with sort_order as 2

Platinum with sort_order as 3

---

Updating Gold to 2 should result in Diamond increasing to 3 and Platinum increasing to 4.

Is there a way to do this in Rails?

Comment: What should happen if Diamond changes to 3? And what should happen if Diamond changes to 4?

Comment: if Diamond changes to 3,Platinum will be updated to 4(this needs to happen if Gold is still at 2)

Comment: I mean. With your initial data (as you wrote in the question). What would happen in both changes I asked?

Comment: That way we will maintain unique sort_order even if user tries to update in any way.

Comment: You are not answering what I asked. I want to know the specific values for Gold, Diamond and Platinum, after both changes. I want to know the operation that must be done after a specific change.

Comment: let's say 
we updated Gold to 2
then Diamond should be updated to 3.
Now sort_order for Platinum and Diamond match , so what should happen is that Platinum should be increment to 4.

Comment: above same process will run if Platinum is updated to 2, then Gold will be increment to 3 resulting Diamond to 4.

Comment: Can you please answer the specific question I made? What will be the values for the three users, giving the initial values in your post, in these 2 cases: case 1) Diamond changes to 3. Case 2) Diamond changes to 4

Comment: Case 1:
if Diamond changes to 3 Platinum should move to 4.

Case 2:
if Diamond changes to 4 Platinum should move to 5.

@Pablo Sorry, I am new to rails actually.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, have you heard of [after_save](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Callbacks/after_save)?

You can define a method to run as a callback every time an object is saved. In this case, you probably only want it to run if the sort order has changed.

Below is some pseudocode - this checks for other models with the same `sort_order` and increments them. Note this will cascade - the `after_save` will also be called on models that are incremented, and so should end up updating everything that needs to be updated.

```
class Foo
  after_save :update_sort_orders, if: :sort_order_changed?

  def update_sort_orders
    Foo.where(sort_order: sort_order).where.not(id: id).each do |foo|
      foo.update_attributes(sort_order: foo.sort_order + 1)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This does use "rails" as was requested in the question. It would be faster and much more reliable to shift everything with one operation. `update foo set sort_order = sort_order + 1 where sort_order >= 1` or something like that. Not sure how to express this in activerecord lingo.

Comment: @Mitch you didn't get me. what i am trying to say is that if a user is trying to update sort_order for a existing element and another element with same sort_order exists , then that existing element's sort_order will increment by 1. same should happen if above operation duplicates another record.

Comment: Got it - I updated it a bit. Let me know what you think now!

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved now.
What i did is that I checked first if record with same sort_order is present.

```
def check_for_duplicates(sort_order)
    foo_list = Foo.all.sort_by { |hash| hash[:sort_order].to_i }
    foo_list.each do |foo|
      if foo['sort_order'] == sort_order
        foo.update_attributes(sort_order: sort_order+ 1)
        sort_order = foo['sort_order']
      end
    end
  end
```

`

Hope this helps someone!!!!! :)